# can't create new folder anywhere in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I'm not able to create new folders in my laptop. Even when I right click on my mouse it's not showing me the new folder option. Is this any spam or not?

I tried the following registry fix:

http://www.vistax64.com/attachments/tutorials/7715d1225832927-new-folder-newfolderfix.reg

but it says that NewFolderFix.reg, didn't work:

`Not all data was succesfully written to the registry. Some keys are open by the system or other processes.`

Comment: Kevin, can you please confirm if it's the same problem outlined in @moses linked article so we know if we need to mark it as a duplicate or if this question is still open to answers?

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for the registry file, but if you're willing to trust it you can either  import it in safe mode or open that file in notepad and manually edit those keys using regedit, then restart.